# How to write "less than" and "greater than" in SOAP messages?

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I have this SOAP request and it is working perfectly. However, I want to change the "EQUALS" to 'greater than' or 'less than', and I couldn't find the right syntax

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://soap.services.cmdbuild.org">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap1:getCardList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:className>Meter</soap1:className>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

         <soap1:queryType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <soap1:filter>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <soap1:name>InstallationDate</soap1:name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <soap1:operator>EQUALS</soap1:operator> <!--I want to change EQUALS to 'less than'-->
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <soap1:value>23/08/2015</soap1:value>
            </soap1:filter>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <soap1:filterOperator>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <soap1:operator></soap1:operator>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <soap1:subquery/>
            </soap1:filterOperator>
         </soap1:queryType>


      </soap1:getCardList>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Replace every occurrence of < wiht `&lt;` and > with `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't like `&lt;` then it's not handling XML encoding correctly.  You can try using CDATA like this:

```
<soap1:operator><![CDATA[>]]></soap1:operator>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it did not work :( 
Can this be related to the namespace that I am using?

Comment: It has nothing to do with namespaces.  If a web service is expecting characters that are restricted in XML (like < and >), then it should expect the sender to encode those characters like TonyP suggested by using &lt; and &gt; or to wrap them in CDATA.

Comment: Anyway, still did not work.
By the way I am using cmdbuild in this regard, does that have any implication?

Comment: The docs state that operator should be things like "AND" and "OR".  They don't claim to support > and <.